# Ten-digit number that satisfy divisibilty rules for 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10&11

Tags: formation-of-numbers, number-theory, number-property

Question:
Arrange the digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 to make a ten-digit Number that satisfies all of the divisibility rules for 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,&11. BONUS: make the number also divisible by 7

Comment: Should I add no-computer tag?

Comment: Why did you have to take down the post? By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, deletions like this will be reverted.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for informing me. I am slowing learning how this all works

Comment: What does "satisfies all of the divisibility rules" mean? That the number needs to actually be divisible by all those divisors? Or just that it needs to follow some well-known necessary (but not necessarily sufficient) rules to be divisible by them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright. First of all,

> 3 and 9 are automatically okay. The sum of the digits from 0 to 9 is 45, which is divisible by 3 and 9, so any number made out of these ten will be divisible by 3 and 9.

Now,

> the last digit MUST be 0, to satisfy 2 and 5 and 10. This also satisfies 6 as well, because it's now divisible by 2 and 3.

Now, let's look at the second-last and third-last digits.

> The second-last digit must be divisible by 4, because the number must be divisible by 4 and 8. The third to last digit must also be even, to make it divisible by 8.

Now

> all we have is 11 (and 7 for extra credit). To satisfy this, we have to make it so that when placing alternating signs between the digits so the result is a multiple of 11. After a bit of trial and error, I came up with 4123975680, which works for everything. It's not divisible by 7, though. I'll keep looking.

As Martin Schulz pointed out in the comments (now deleted),

> 9165784320 is divisible by 7

Comment: I have 1385679240 & 7165932840  neither divisible by 7

Comment: My theory is that the number has to end in 240 or 640 or 840 but your answer totally disproved that.

Comment: "The second-last digit must be divisible by 4, because the number must be divisible by 4 and 8." This is not true. For a counterexample, 120 is divisible by 4 and 8, but its second-last digit is not divisible by 4.

Comment: the correct wording would be *the last 2 digits must be divisible by 4 and the last 3 digits must be divisible by 8*. In fact we just need to check for divisibility by 8, since that implies divisibility by 4 as well

Answer (score 21):

This is a good problem to attack by computer:

> It turns out that there are 7344 solutions, including 1056 to the bonus.

So I thought, how far can we go?

> And it just happens that 2438195760, 3785942160, 4753869120 and 4876391520 are exactly those permutations of `0123456789` divisible by each of 1 through 18, and none of them are divisible by 19.

Code used (Python 3 IDLE):

> ```
> >>> import itertools
> >>> normal=[]
> >>> bonus=[]
> >>> extra=[]
> >>> for i in itertools.permutations('123456789'):
> ...     n=int(''.join(i+('0',)))
> ...     if 0==n%8==n%9==n%11:
> ...             normal.append(n)
> ...             if 0==n%7:
> ...                     bonus.append(n)
> ...                     if 0==n%13==n%16==n%17:
> ...                             extra.append(n)
> ...
> >>> len(normal)
> 7344
> >>> len(bonus)
> 1056
> >>> extra
> [2438195760, 3785942160, 4753869120, 4876391520]
> >>> [i%19 for i in extra]
> [12, 13, 17, 5]
> ```

Comment: Oh my goodness, that is amazing. I’m totally  Computer illiterate. you have to totally teach me how to do this problem on a computer.

Comment: @DeNel I used Python 3, I'll attach some code that I used in a few moments.

Comment: @DeNel, the general idea is to construct every permutation of the ten digits and then check the divisors of each of those numbers. It’s a pretty simple program to write (for one who knows how, of course), and a computer can check all of the combinations very quickly, even though there are a lot of them.

Comment: boboquack, As @ExcitedRaichu pointed out, there’s no need to check divisibility by 9, since it is guaranteed by the choice of digits.

Comment: @prl Lucky this isn’t code-golf then! It’s not much of a time cost for me anyway, the program runs in about 0.3 seconds for me.